# How to get the (escaped) command executed in a Node.js child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can run a command in a Node.js child process like this, with all its args safely escaped:

```js
import {spawn} from 'child_process';

const proc = spawn('ls', ['./folder 1']);
```

If such a command fails, I want to print the full command to stdout so I can copy it and debug it manually.

It's not sufficient to just use this below, because of the unescaped space in the resulting output:

```js
console.log(proc.spawnargs.join(' '));
// Prints `ls ./folder 1`
```

How can I get the escaped command from this process?

Currently I rely on a crude regex matcher like below, but I'm wondering if there's a better, safer and more comprehensive solution.

```js
args
  .map(arg =>
    /[\t\n\r "#$%&'()*;<=>?\\[`|~]/.test(arg)
      ? `'${arg.replaceAll("'", "\\'")}'`
      : arg
  )
  .join(' ');
```